# Adding document to an embedded array after conditional search

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Below is my code returned after the commant db.slist.findOne()

How do I add an id to the array with "iname"  as "Soap"?
I need to write a query that seaches the all the "itemlist"array in the collection and if the any document inside an embedded document have "iname" as "Soap", a new row should be inserted above "iname:"Soap" as "itemID" and set an item ID myself. Can someone help me find the correct query for it?

Also this seems like a hard question, please let me know if you are finding hard to understand the question.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5914213e9f75f9119575c1d7"),
    "name" : "Athif",
    "age" : 23,
    "address" : {
        "house" : "675/38B",
        "street" : "West Hill",
        "city" : "Chungam",
        "pincode" : 676507
    },
    "itemlist" : [
        {
            "iname" : "Soap",
            "quantity" : 2,
            "price" : 10,
            "rate" : 20
        },
        {
            "iname" : "helmet",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "price" : 500,
            "rate" : 500
        },
        {
            "iname" : "Table",
            "quantity" : 2,
            "price" : 5000,
            "rate" : 10000
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: There can be multiple objects with iname as "Soap" in itemlist array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating array elements mongodb provides positional operator `$`. when you apply query to find any array elements the positional operator `$` holds the position of that embedded document that can be modified in update operation. So, here you go!( suppose your collection name is demo)

```
db.demo.update({ "itemlist.iname":"Soap" }, { $set:{"itemlist.$.itemID":"your_id"}})
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. An additional question if you don't mind, the above code is updating the document for this particular object only. If I have another object, a different person with a shopping list, and he has "Soap" in his "itemlist", can I add the "itemId" to both "Soap" document at the same time with single command? Or do I need to do this separately for each person with "Soap" in their item list?

Comment: welcome! @HishamMubarak you should keep in mind if the `itemlist` has more documents with `iname` soap it will apply update to the first matching document leaving else untouched.